# Custom widget not appearing on front end

Tags: theme-development, widgets, widget-text

I have the following widget location defined in my theme's `functions.php`:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Opening Hours', 'transparent' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-hours',
    'description' => __( 'Appears on the front page', 'transparent' ),  
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
```

This widget location is appearing in Admin > Appearance > Widgets, and I have a HTML text widget in this location.

In my theme's index.php, I have the following code:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-hours' ) ) : ?>
    <p class="opening-hours">
      <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-hours' ); ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, on the [front end of the website](http://www.bibandtucker.net.au/test/), the widget text is not appearing.  It should be below the navigation menu.

Can you provide troubleshooting advice please?

Comment: First, theres a html syntax error with this, the widget that will be generated is inside a div, and you're trying to display the widget inside a paragraph tag, which is not going to work properly. In short, a paragraph element may not contain other block elements. So change `<p class="opening-hours">` to `<div class="opening-hours">`

Comment: Also, looks like the widget appears on the other pages on the site, correct?

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my side. You have some other issue that is not related to this code you've posted

Comment: Oh, silly me, I have a front-page.php without the widget code in it.  Thank you @passatgt.